# Horizontal line after title of ToC

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

when I have 2 or more pages of ToC horizontal line after title of Toc moves to last page of ToC. Is there any option to force that horizontal line appear only on first page of ToC? When I have only 1 page of ToC, output is OK!

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (3cm,-5.5cm) $) -- ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.5cm,-5.5cm) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \clearpage

    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

edit with header/footer:

```
%%begin preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%%begin ToC, LoF & LoT renaming 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill \textit{Table of Contents}}     %%Table of contents name change
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill \textit{List of Figures}}     %%List of figures name change
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill \textit{List of Tables}}       %%List of tables name change
%%end ToC, LoF & LoT renaming 

%%begin upper case in section and toc
\ifdefined\texorpdfstring\else\newcommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1}\fi
\let\oldsection\section

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar{\oldsection*}{\@Section}}
\newcommand{\@sSection}[2][]{%
    \oldsection*{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\@Section}[2][]{%
    \def\shortsec{#1}%
    \ifx\shortsec\empty%
    \oldsection{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
    \else%
    \oldsection[\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}]{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}
    \fi}
\makeatother
%%end upper case in section and toc

%%begin section/subsection/subsubsection modifying
\AtBeginEnvironment{adjustwidth}{%
    \titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesection}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
    \titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesubsection}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
    \titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesubsubsubsection}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\theparagraph}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}
    \titleformat{\subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\thesubparagraph}}{-0.5pt}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}}

    \titlespacing*{\section}{-2cm}{0.6cm}{0.6cm}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{0.4cm}{0.4cm}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
    \titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
    \titlespacing*{\paragraph}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
    \titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{-2cm}{0.2cm}{0.2cm}
}
%%end section/subsection/subsubsection modifying

%%begin new command for generating table of contents, list of figures and list of tables
\newcommand\tocloflot{%
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{\string\hrule}
    \clearpage
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname
    \listoffigures
    \addtocontents{lof}{\string\hrule\par\bigskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \clearpage
    \csname phantomsection\endcsname
    \listoftables
    \addtocontents{lot}{\string\hrule\par\bigskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
    \clearpage
}

%\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{ex}}
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{3ex}}
%\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{3ex}}

%%end new command for generating table of contents, list of figures and list of tables





\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}      %%images are kept in a folder named images under the directory of the main document

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}                                                    %%odabir veličine papira
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}      %%podešavanje margina
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3cm,headsep=0.5cm}                        %%podešavanje headinga
\geometry{includefoot=false}                                                %%podešavanje footinga

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}     %%paragraf uvodni razmak

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %%delete default header line

\newcommand{\thenextpage}{\number\numexpr\thepage+1\relax}      %%new command for next page reference

\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}}        %%changing linespacing on a single row of a table

%%begin page borders
\SetBgOpacity{100.0}    %% Select opacity
\SetBgScale{1}          %% Select scale factor of logo
\SetBgAngle{0}          %% Select rotation of logo
\SetBgColor{black}      %% Select color
\SetBgContents{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=0pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-1cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);

    \draw [line width=1.5pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-14.85cm) $) -- ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-14.85cm) $);

    \node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1cm)$) {\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[r]{\scriptsize\selectfont Reproduction or any use not conformity with the intended\\
                \scriptsize\selectfont application is not permissible.}}};
    \node[anchor=south] at ($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1cm)$) {\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[l]{\scriptsize\selectfont Nachdruck oder Verwendung, die nicht der beabsichtigten\\
                \scriptsize\selectfont Anwendung entspricht, ist nicht zulässig.}}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%%end page borders

%%begin firstpage footer
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
    \fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
    \fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
    \fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
    \fancyfoot[C]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+(2.5cm,1cm)$) {
            \begin{tabular}{
                @{}p{3cm}@{}
                @{}p{2.92cm}@{}|
                @{}>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|
                @{}>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|
                @{}>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|
                @{}>{\centering \scriptsize}p{2.3cm}@{}|
                @{}p{1.5cm}@{}
                @{}p{0.8cm}@{}
            }
            \cline{3-8}
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{hh}
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{hhh}
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{jjj}
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{3-8}
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{jjj}
            \bigstrut\\ \hline
            \multirow{-2.3}{=}{jjj}
            & gg
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{gg}
            \bigstrut\\ \hline
            \multirow{-3}{=}{g}
            & gg
            & \multicolumn{3}{l}{g}
            \bigstrut\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{g}
            & \raggedright g
            & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{g}
            & g
            & g
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
            \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ggg}
            & \centering hhh
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ggg}
            & gg
            & g
            \bigstrut\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{gg}
            & \raggedright gg
            & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l|}{gg}
            & gg:
            & gg
            \bigstrut\\ \cline{7-8} 
            \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ggg}
            & \centering ggg
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{gg}
            & gg
            & gg
            \bigstrut\\
            \end{tabular}%
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
%%end firstpage footer

%%begin default header for all pages; except first page style
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
\fancyhead[C]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5cm,-1cm)$) {
        \begin{tabular}{
            @{}>{\centering}p{4cm}@{}|
            @{}p{5.95cm}@{}|
            @{}p{2.50cm}@{}|
            @{}p{2.50cm}@{}|
            @{}>{\scriptsize}p{1.50cm}@{}
            @{}>{\footnotesize}p{1.00cm}@{}
        }
        gg
        & hh
        & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{hhh}
        & hh
        & hh
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{5-6}
        & \centering hh
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{hh}
        & hhhh
        & hh
        \bigstrut\\ \cline{2-6}
        & hh
        & hh
        & hh
        & hh
        & hh
        \bigstrut[b]\\ \cline{5-6}
        & \centering hh
        & \centering hh
        & \centering hh
        & hh
        & hh
        \bigstrut\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%%end default header for all pages; except first page style

%%end preamble
\begin{document}
    %%titlepage begin
    \sloppy     %% sprijecava da text ode van margine
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}       %%\fancypagestyle{firstpage}

    %%begin podešavanje margina, headinga i footinga za početnu stranicu
    \newgeometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm},
        includehead=false,
        includefoot=true,footskip=10cm
    }
    %%end podešavanje margina, headinga i footinga za početnu stranicu

    \vspace*{6cm}                   %%6cm vertical offset
    \begin{center}
        \Huge Some random text\\
        \large Some random text\\~\\
        \Huge Some random text\\
        \large Some random text
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}                 %%fill page with empty space
    \clearpage  
    %%titlepage end

    \restoregeometry                %%restore to default header for all pages; except first page style
    \tocloflot

    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}

        \section{Section}
            \lipsum
            \lipsum
            \lipsum
            \lipsum 
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I tried to move the tikzpicture in front, but while it takes up no space (same as `\hbox{}`), it still causes `\tableofcontents` to move down one line,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}
    \AddThispageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (3cm,-5.5cm) $) -- ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.5cm,-5.5cm) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage

    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title} 
\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to use tocloft, you can use `\addtocontents` for formatting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\hrule height1pt}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-\ht\strutbox\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{1pt}}\par}

    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title}
    \section{title} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like solution with `\addtocontents`. Is it possible to change thickness of line?

Comment: Odd argument protocol, but yes.  It turns out the `\string` wasn't needed after all.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more modification, sorry :(. In mean time I made modifications with margins. Is it possible to extend horizontal line 2 cm to the left; as shown in picture https://ibb.co/k9oEZJ

Comment: Note that \rule adds extra vertical space compared to \hrule, and requires a \par after.

Answer (score 2):

Why using a hammersledge to get a simple rule when it's so easy to obtain with `tocloft`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multido}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\\\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\vspace*{3ex}}
\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
 \clearpage

\multido{\i = 1 + 1}{27}{\section{title} \lipsum[\i]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but when I include `tocloft`my header is not appearing anymore, do you know how to solve this. So from package `tocloft`I want to add only this line after title of ToC all other option I want to disable. :)

Comment: What do you mean by  ‘header’ here? The small text above the text area in each page?

Comment: Im sorry my mistake, I didn't post that in original document I have footer only in first page, and in all others header. Yes.

Comment: Could you edit your post to provide the code for footers/headers?

Comment: I have added, for now Im using `\addtocontents{toc}{\string\hrule} \addtocontents{lof}{\string\hrule\par\bigskip} \addtocontents{lot}{\string\hrule\par\bigskip}` its solution from @John Kormylo. Your solution is written in code but its commented. Just for info. :)